# Why does my node-type-specific hook not work

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I have implemented a `hook_node_info()` as follows:

```
function mymodule2_node_info(){
  return array(
    'mynode1' => array(
      'name' => 'MyNode1',
      'base' => 'mynode1',
      'description' => t('A Description of MyNode1'),
      'has_title' => TRUE,
      'title_label' => 'Title',
    ),
  );
}
```

I'd specified the 'base' property as 'mynode1', So I would expect that an implementation of `mynode1_view()` would work when this node is viewed.

```
function mynode1_view($node, $view_mode){

}
```

But I get the error messages instead:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in node_build_content() (line 1413 of 
C:\wamp\vhosts\mydrupal72\modules\node\node.module).
EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in
 entity_extract_ids() (line 7880 of C:\wamp\vhosts\mydrupal72\includes\common.inc).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to return $node at the end of your `mynode1_view` function. (This is different from most hooks, which generally modify the variable by reference).  You may have missed this. See [this comment](https://api.drupal.org/comment/50838#comment-50838).

Comment: Wow! Worked like magic, thanks. Seems Drupal documentation does not make any notes on the little but hugely important detail. I'd wasted so much time already

Comment: @okeyxyz _The passed $node parameter should be modified as necessary and returned so it can be properly presented._ is what he documentation says... if you feel that's unclear or ambiguous perhaps raise a feature request for improved docs? Hard to see how it can be improved though